# Lenght and width values don't do anything - Here-API test web site

Tags: here-api

Trying to determine best values for testing on this site: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet to proof here-api calls. Can't seem to add any length or width values that make any difference at all. All others work fine. Even using metric defaults, I can increase the number to well beyond the norm and it still routes, until the number is too extreme and it doesn't route at all.

Answer (score 0):

They work as expected. Below I have chosen a route from  Causeway St, Boston, MA to Allston,Boston, MA. When I provide width parameter the route changes due to restrictions on truck width in the previous route.

Route without width parameter: 
[image]

Route with width parameter added: 
[image]

Also, there is a restriction on the max width and max length you are allowed to provide. That is why it doesnt route when you exceed these values. 
You can debug and check the response of the routing api where it gives you the exact response(where the reason is provided for not routing).

You can check more about the api parameters here- https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Thanks very much. I was able to bear out the same in another test as well. So the only thing I cannot rectify is trailers. Adding them doesn't seem to make a difference, and will will even let me route 4 trailers across New Hampshire for example, which as far as I can tell, has a limit of 2 trailers.